# SDL.dll is missing from my computer - VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I'm trying to compile a SDL-program I've written, but when I do, this error shows up:

> The program can't start because SDL.dll is missing from your computer.
>   Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem

I have no idea as to why. I have SDL.dll.

- I have put it in the correct folder: `C:\Windows\System32`.
- I have the correct PATHS to all the SDL headers and such as well.

VS says:

> Build succeeded: 1

and THEN the error above pops up on screen.

Comment: If you have a 64-bit version of Windows then it needs to go into c:\windows\syswow64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add it into your debug folder or whatever directory your program is currently located at.

Comment: That didn't make any difference.

Comment: @user1068249 what about in the folder with your .cpp files in it? That's where mine are usually located.

Comment: That's the folder that needed the dll files! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

`SDL.dll` has to either be in the same directory as your application, or in a directory that's in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

If`SDL.dll` is 32-bit and you're running a 64-bit system you have to place the dll into `/Windows/SysWOW64/` rather than `/Windows/System32/`, which is used for 64-bit dlls.

EDIT:
You probably shouldn't be deploying your DLLs by copying them into the System32 directory, unless they're common libraries that are used by several applications, and even then I would use discretion. For example, an application could update the DLL, which could break other applications that rely on an older version of the library.

Instead, copy the DLLs into the same directory that the executable is being built in. If you're building and executing with Visual Studio it will look for the DLL in the Project directory, where your source files are probably located.

Comment: Most misleading directory structure ever.

Comment: hi, if I would like to put the SDL.dll into specific folder under system folder, how to do it E.g. /Windows/SysWOW64/ABC/SDL.dll.

Comment: I don't think you can. You should really just deploy your application with the DLLs in the same directory as the executable, not in System32. I'm editing the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Just place your SDL.dll in the same folder and your problem will be solved.
And to answer to your problem with the PATH, you can specify in visual studio where he will look for executables while debugging. Maybe this isn't set correctly and that's why VS can't find SDL.dll?