# dll A calling dll B function in different folder location

Tags: c++, dll

I have 2 dlls which are A & B and both of them will deploy to different folder location.

for example,

```
Dll A in C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Project


Dll B in C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Project\B Folder
```

how dll A load dll B instead of using LoadLibrary method ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use `LoadLibrary`. You compile DLL A with a reference to DLL B, using B's headers and `.lib`. Then you let the system loader resolve dependencies. At worse you use a manifest ([SxS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly)) to fine-tune control the DLL to be loaded at runtime.

`LoadLibrray` should be used only when you need to do runt-time feature on-off switch, when you need to exhibit a certain behavior only when a DLL is present and perhaps of a certain version. Some licensing schemes may require dynamic loading, but almost always thay can be better addressed. OS dependencies (eg. behave one way on XP, another on Win7, to leverage newer OS's features) is an acceptable use of `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I just have done an example and try out your suggested solution. However, it shows "required to locate the dll same location with exe" when I try to run my sample exe, you can download the project from my skydrive

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=233E2A690341BB1D!366&authkey=!AMi2eWuUB7t2aSU&ithint=file%2c.rar

Comment: Add `B Folder` to `PATH` or, preferably, deploy a manifest and specify the location. See [Building C/C++ Side-by-side Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235512.aspx)

Comment: any easy solution ? because I have tested, created few projects Dll A, B and console.

Inside dll A included some methods from dll B

Then add dll A and lib in console project and run.

At last, it shows can't find the dll B, because it was in the folder and different location from dll A

Comment: at last, I did not have add B folder path to system PATH, but add the dll to system folder(32/64 bit)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652136/sdl-dll-is-missing-from-my-computer-vs-2010